# MVC image resize depending on amount in folder

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have recent started using MVC 5, i have been stuck with this for a while
what i want to do is resize a image depending on how many images in a folder
for example
if one image max width to be 100%
if two image's max width to be 50%
if three image's max width to 33%
and so on
but i also would like the images to re size depending on the page size
i have tried styling like

```html
<div style="position: relative; max-width: 24%; background: White; vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1">
  <img style="margin: 10%; height: 80%; width: 80%;" src="~/Images/Example1.jpg" />
</div>
```

which is great if only 4 images are been used, but i would like to re size depending on how many images are used
I have also have tried a foreach loop like

```html
@foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/ExampleFolder"), "*.jpg")) { var img = new FileInfo(imgPath);

<div style="position: relative; max-width: ; background: White; vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1">
  <img style="margin: 10%; height: 80%; width: 80%;" src="@Url.Content(String.Format(" ~/Images/ExampleFolder/{0} ", img.Name))" />
</div>


}
```

Comment: There are far, far better ways of doing what you are trying to do. Try adding HTML and JavaScript tags and see what those guys can come up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this (not tested):

```
@{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/ExampleFolder"), "*.jpg");
    if (files.Length > 0) 
    {
        double width = 100d / (double)files.Length;
        foreach (var imgPath in files)
        {
            var img = new FileInfo(imgPath);

            <div style="position: relative; background: White; vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1">
                <img style="margin: 10%; height: 80%; width: @(width)%;" src="@Url.Content(String.Format(" ~/Images/ExampleFolder/{0} ", img.Name))" />
            </div>


        }
    }
}
```